# 2 different styles in 1 paragraph

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to change the color and align the text below in the same `div`, is there a way to do that?
If I use `style="color: white;"` then `text align: center;` won't appear.

```
<div>
  <p style="text-align: center;"> 
  Views: <span id="Views">0</span> 
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try `style="text-align: center;color: white;"`?

Comment: No, I haven't but that worked! Thanks

Comment: Can you show what you've tried. You should avoid using local style tags too. Create a style sheet and use that to control the style of the div, paragraph, span, etc.

Comment: Are you trying to change the color of the `<p>` AND `<span>` to white? I'm a bit confused by what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I was trying to change the color of "Views" and "0" to white and what Scott told me worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add style after `text-align:center`.

```
<div>
    <p  style = "text-align: center;color: red;"> 
    Views: <span id="Views" style="color: red;">0</span> 
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have other code that might be affecting the styling, but this *should* work if you don't (the CSS `background` is just to show the white text):

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p style="text-align: center; color: white;"> 
  Views: <span id="Views">0</span> 
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I do have a black background which is why i wanted my color to be white, thanks for the help though.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <p> Views : <span id="views">0</span>
</div>
```

But it's better to put the CSS in a file, and not in "style"